# Why does the PS3 refuse to download even though there is space?

Tags: ps3

My husband has a Ps3. Whenever he wants to download a game from the Playstation store, it says that he has 2 accounts and must deactivate a device. We have 4 PS3's all active. No he does have 2 email accounts but he hasn't used the one in years for the Ps3. No we did have to throw one out because we couldn't get it to come back on to deactivate it. It had been tempermental for a while. What do we do? He only uses the one address to sign in now on all the one's we have.

Comment: There is a reddit thread [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS3/comments/k745rr/how_to_get_past_0_ps3_systems_activated_for_this/) that might solve your issue.